# How to get JsonPath for nodeSelector

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there a way to get JsonPath for nodeSelector key word from `kubectl` command line?

If I run the `kubectl explain deployment --recursive` command, it will output a list of all key words:

```
apiVersion  <string>
kind    <string>
metadata    <Object>
   annotations  <map[string]string>
   clusterName  <string>
   creationTimestamp    <string>
   deletionGracePeriodSeconds   <integer>
   deletionTimestamp    <string>
   finalizers   <[]string>
   generateName <string>
   generation   <integer>
   initializers <Object>
      pending   <[]Object>
         name   <string>
      result    <Object>
         apiVersion <string>
         code   <integer>
         details    <Object>
            causes  <[]Object>
               field    <string>
               message  <string>
               reason   <string>
            group   <string>
            kind    <string>
...
```

This list is quite long and with key word like `nodeSelector` it is hard to see that JsonPath is `spec.template.spec.nodeSelector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to do it is to convert  output to correct YAML format like this:
(I've done several replacements and deletions to get this output. Unfortunately, there are no native options for kubectl to achieve it.)

```
   apiVersion: 'string'
   kind: 'string'
   metadata:
      annotations: 'map[string]string'
      clusterName: 'string'
      creationTimestamp: 'string'
      deletionGracePeriodSeconds: 'integer'
      deletionTimestamp: 'string'
      finalizers: '[]string'
      generateName: 'string'
      generation: 'integer'
      initializers:
         pending:
            name: 'string'
         result:
            apiVersion: 'string'
            code: 'integer'
            details:
               causes:
                  field: 'string'
                  message: 'string'
                  reason: 'string'
...
```

Now you can apply the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507208/how-do-i-recursively-flatten-a-yaml-file-into-a-json-object-where-keys-are-dot-s) stackoverflow question to get flattened output like this:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "string",
  "kind": "string",
  "metadata.annotations": "map[string]string",
  "metadata.clusterName": "string",
  "metadata.creationTimestamp": "string",
  "metadata.deletionGracePeriodSeconds": "integer",
  "metadata.deletionTimestamp": "string",
  "metadata.finalizers": "[]string",
  "metadata.generateName": "string",
  "metadata.generation": "integer",
  "metadata.initializers.pending.name": "string",
  "metadata.initializers.result.apiVersion": "string",
  "metadata.initializers.result.code": "integer",
  "metadata.initializers.result.details.causes.field": "string",
  "metadata.initializers.result.details.causes.message": "string",
  "metadata.initializers.result.details.causes.reason": "string",
...
}
```

Then you can filter or search the result to get the values you want.